# Redirecting URL after user logged out to previous page opened

Tags: security, redirect, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC based application in which when the session is expired, user is automatically logged out. After logging in again I want to redirect the user to the last page on which he was, how can I do it. Currently, this is happening

```
User is on: http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/home/#/access/userManagement
```

Now when session expired,

```
User is on: http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/auth/login#/access/userManagement
```

After loggin in again,

```
User is on: http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/home/
```

here is my config

```
<security:form-login
                login-page="/auth/login"
                default-target-url="/home/"
                always-use-default-target="false"
                authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true"/>
```

what more setting I need to redirect user to the last opened page???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own like:

```
<security:form-login
                login-page="/auth/login"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                always-use-default-target="false"
                authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true"/>

<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class=".....MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
```

This `MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler` could extend [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) .

Following a successful authentication, it decides on the redirect destination, based on the following scenarios:

- If the `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` property is set to `true`, the `defaultTargetUrl` will be used for the destination. Any `DefaultSavedRequest` stored in the session will be removed.
- If the `targetUrlParameter` has been set on the request, the value will be used as the destination. Any `DefaultSavedRequest` will again be removed.
- If a `DefaultSavedRequest` is found in the `RequestCache` (as set by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` to record the original destination before the authentication process commenced), a redirect will be performed to the Url of that original destination. The `DefaultSavedRequest` object will remain cached and be picked up when the redirected request is received (See `SavedRequestAwareWrapper`).
- If no `DefaultSavedRequest` is found, it will delegate to the base class.

So basically, you need to replace default target URL behavior and override it with your own.

Hope this helps.Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, while implementing I stuck in another situation can u please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609621/setdefaulttargeturl-is-not-working