# setDefaultTargetUrl is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to redirect my page based on some hidden value in login.jsp page, here is my code

```
public class AuthenticationHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private final String HASH_URL = "hashURL";

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);

        String hashValue = request.getParameter(HASH_URL);
        if(hashValue != null){
            if(!hashValue.isEmpty()){
                setDefaultTargetUrl("/home/" + hashValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that hashValue is getting latest values from login.jsp page, but its always moving the site /home/ page, here is my configs

```
<security:form-login
                login-page="/auth/login"
                default-target-url="/home/"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already quoted this in your previous problem [Redirecting URL after user logged out to previous page opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563919/redirecting-url-after-user-logged-out-to-previous-page-opened/17565267?noredirect=1#comment25632624_17565267)

```
Following a successful authentication SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler: 
If the alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl property is set to true, the defaultTargetUrl 
will be used for the destination. 
Any DefaultSavedRequest stored in the session will be removed.
```

So you should set always-use-default-target="false" also you can remove default-target-url attribute.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling `setDefaultTargetUrl` while your application is running. It's a field on the class, not a local variable, so it will apply to all users of your site.

Take a look at the code you are extending in `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. It's essential you understand how it works if you are going to call the superclass method. You call `super.onAuthenticationSuccess` as the first thing in your method. This will take the current value of `defaultTargetUrl` (or a cached request) and redirect to that URL. You are setting the property *after* the redirect has taken place.

As I said you shouldn't be setting the property at all at runtime. I's guess your method should be more like

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String hashValue = request.getParameter(HASH_URL);
    if(hashValue != null) {
        response.sendRedirect(getDefaultTargetUrl() + "/" + hashValue;
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(getDefaultTargetUrl());
    }
}
```

You probable don't need to extend a class at all. Just implement `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` directly yourself. It will be easier to understand what's going on without the inheritance involved.

Not that if you're using a custom handler class, namespace properties like `always-use-default-target` which affect the default handler won't have any effect.